# How can I apply multiple filter with prisma?

Tags: prisma, prisma2, remix.run

I've an ecommerce project where i was working on filtering the products using prisma query.

1.) http://localhost:3000/products/[category] ---> should return all products based on catgeory

2.) http://localhost:3000/products/dress?tipe=basic&tipe=pattern&color=black&size=S ---> should return catgerory with filters applied

Prisma Query look like this

Schema

```
model Product {
  id         String @id @default(cuid())
  name       String
  desription String
  image      String
  price      String
  color      String
  category   String
  arrival    String
  size       String
  tipe       String
}
```

Query

```
{
      products: await prisma.product.findMany({
        where: {
          category,
          tipe: {
            in: tipe, //  [ 'pattern', 'hoodie', 'zipper' ] get from searchParams
          },
          color:{
            in: color
          },
          size: {
            in: size
          }
        },
      }),
    }
```

But the query return []

Not sure why this query not works! Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by dynamically constructing the where clause in [findMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#findmany) query. So in your API you can check the query parameters which are obtained and based on that construct the clause. For Example you can do something like this:

```js
 const where = {
   tipe: 'basic'
  };

  if(params.colour){
    where.colour = params.colour
  }

  if(params.size){
    where.size = params.size
  }

  const results = await prisma.product.findMany({
    where,
  });
```